# bounded intervals and partitions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can you please check my proof?

**Question**

> Let $I$ be a bounded interval of the form $I = (a, b)$ or $I= [a, b)$ for some real numbers $a< b$. Let $I_1, I_2, ..., I_n$ be a partition of $I$. Prove that one of the intervals $I_j$ in this partition is of the form $I_j = ( c, b)$ or $I_j = [c, b)$ for some $a\leq c \leq b$. (Hint: prove by contradiction. First show that if $I_j$ is not of the form $(c, b)$ or $[c, b)$ for any $a\leq c\leq b$, then $\sup I_j$ is strictly less than b.

**Answer**

For the sake of contradiction, Suppose $I_j=(c,b]\in P$ where $P:=\{I_1,I_2,...,I_j,...,I_n\}$

then $(c,b]\subseteq I$ (by definition of partition),

$\therefore b\in I$

but, the interval I:=(a,b) does not contain b. !!Contradiction.

My problem is that I haven't used the hint. I can not see why do we need it.

Comment: No, your argument does not work. Obviously no $I_j$ can be of the form you suggested. Just as obvious, no $I_j$ is actually an apple. For the sake of contradiction you do not start by assuming that one of the $I_j$s is an apple. You assume that no $I_j$ has the form $(c,b)$ and does not have the form $(c,b]$. *That*, and only that should be your assumption.

Comment: oh! I totally misunderstood the hint. my only assumption should be (c,b) and [c,b) do not exist in P?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your proof as follows.

For the sake of contradiction, Suppose $I_j=(c_j,b_j]\in P$ where $P:=\{I_1,I_2,...,I_j,...,I_n\}$

then $(c_j,b_j]\subseteq I$ (by definition of partition),

$\therefore b_j\in I$

but, the interval I:=(a,b) does not contain b.

So each $b_j<b$.

Then $\max_{j} b_j<b$.

Then an interval $(\max_{j} b_j,b)$ is disjoint with each $I_j$!!

Contradiction.

Comment: I did not understand the last line.

Comment: $I_j\cap (\max_{i} b_i,b)=(c_j,b_j]\cap (\max_{i} b_i,b)\subset (c_j,b_j]\cap (b_j,b)=\varnothing$